# How to display facebook real time update on the browser

Tags: facebook, web-applications, browser, real-time

I have a callback.php file that gets called by facebook and the update is stored in $updates. I want to display the contents of $updates on the webpage every time $updates changes. How can i do this? I have heard about Comet and Ajax.. 
what is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: JS setinterval, poll server for updates every x seconds. Harder: HTML5 Websockets (not that hard when you get into it though).

Comment: hi christian, is there a way the server can push the updates instead of me polling it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need the [Real time update Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) from Facebook.